# Embedding Excel Instance in VB.net webbrowser

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net

Hello I am trying to create a VB.net windows form that has an embedded instance of Excel within the form.  I have found that there is a way to use the Webbrowser control to open Excel in that control using the following

```
  WebBrowserDupChannels.Navigate(strFileName)
```

However, when implementing this line of code via a button click, there is a pop up that asks to open or save the file.  After Open is selected, the file opens in its own Excel instance and the web browser is blank.   I thought maybe implementing the GetActiveWindow via

```
    Public Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
```

would work but I am not sure how to grab the instance of Excel opened within .net, especially if the user has other instances of Excel open.

Comment: Office Excel stopped supporting being loaded directly into Internet Explorer since Office 2007, and Internet Explorer stopped supporting ActiveX/OLE objects being loaded into it a while ago too. You're looking at very, very old documentation.

Comment: What would be the current way of supporting having an instance of Excel in the .net windows form?    Could the instance window be grabbed somehow?

Comment: I don’t believe it’s supported at all now. The last time I tried to get Office OLE working (over 10 years ago now) it always opened up Word and Excel in their own application windows as-normal.